# was thinking of getting an Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 for my dell optiplex 7010 usff 0MN1TX motherboard but wanted to ask some questions first

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, motherboard, dell-optiplex

i know this may be a dumb question because anything i have seen implies i would need an antenna but looking at the motherboard continues to raise questions such as would it fit (the motherboard is an 0MN1TX) and i was wondering if i would need an antenna for it and if so which i should get this is my first pc and honestly just want it to have a faster internet connection than 20 kbps with the usb thing that came with it i also intent to upgrade the cpu and ram to the best of my abilities my confusion stems from the metal pieces on the board seemingly right where the antenna points are on an Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 any sort of help for how to upgrade my pc would be much appreciated-sincerely Phin

Comment: Please try to use sentences.

Comment: 802.11 (aka WiFi 5/6/6E) devices need antenna(s) to properly function.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need an antenna. Otherwise, Wi-Fi performance and range will be seriously affected. On the OptiPlex 7010 USFF, the antenna is an external device with a proprietary connector that is routed to the Wi-Fi card internally.

In the [OptiPlex 7010 Ultra Small Form Factor (USFF) Removal Guide for the Wireless Module, Internal Antenna, System Fan, Memory and Heatsink](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/000125338/optiplex-7010-ultra-small-form-factor-usff-removal-guide-for-the-wireless-module-internal-antenna-system-fan-memory-and-heatsink) you can see where the internal antenna cable would be.

If you don’t have it, you can probably get the required cable from a replacement part seller. Check first whether the case has the required hole in it. Furthermore, you need the external antenna part, which may also be available.

---

A USB Wi-Fi adapter should not be limited to the speed you mention. The “cheaper solution” may be to ask a (new!) question about that, including the exact make and model of the adapter and which USB port it is connected to.